# Woocommerce Template Files not allowing using div

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce

So I added to my Woocommerce Template Files to my Wordpress custom theme woocommerce folder, I can edit files, but when I try use div, it automatically removes them and sometimes all content inside it. Can't find any solutions, any way to walk around it?

There is my my-order.php inside mytheme/woocommerce folder, I edited few classes to change to bootstrap look, but when I wanted to wrap any line of code with div with class, but doesn't show up in page.

```
<?php
/**
 * My Orders - Deprecated
 *
 * @deprecated 2.6.0 this template file is no longer used. My Account shortcode uses orders.php.
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

$my_orders_columns = apply_filters(
    'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns',
    array(
        'order-number'  => esc_html__( 'Order', 'woocommerce' ),
        'order-date'    => esc_html__( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ),
        'order-status'  => esc_html__( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'order-total'   => esc_html__( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ),
        'order-actions' => '&nbsp;',
    )
);

$customer_orders = get_posts(
    apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query',
        array(
            'numberposts' => $order_count,
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
            'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
        )
    )
);

if ( $customer_orders ) : ?>

    <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_title', esc_html__( 'Recent orders', 'woocommerce' ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></h2>
<div class="common-table table-1 desk">
    <table class="table">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( $my_orders_columns as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                    <th class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) :
                $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
                $a=0;
                ?>
                <tr class="order">
                    <?php foreach ( $my_orders_columns as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                        <td class="<?php if ($a == 0 ) {echo $x="text-start"; $a++;} ?>">
                            <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
                                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number(); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                                </a>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-date' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <time datetime="<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_date_created()->date( 'c' ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ); ?></time>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-total' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                /* translators: 1: formatted order total 2: total order items */
                                printf( _n( '%1$s for %2$s item', '%1$s for %2$s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                                ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                $actions = wc_get_account_orders_actions( $order );

                                if ( ! empty( $actions ) ) {
                                    foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) { // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                                        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Does the other contents in the file is displayed ? Make sure the file copied to the theme is loaded instead of the file in WooCommerce folder

Comment: Yes, it's working, I changed some other code without problem, but when I wanted to add all code table to div with class, it just disappeared

Comment: Can you add the code to the question ?

Comment: I did correction, actually when I use div, it just remove div and sometimes content inside, also added code how it looks, so the <div class="common-table table-1 desk"> doesn't show up when I check page.

Comment: Are you using my-orders.php inorder to override for my account page ? From 2.6, orders.php file is being used .

Comment: Thank you, you are right! I should have used orders.php and not my-orders.php, now it works.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Changed editing from my-orders.php to orders.php and now it's working. They are same files, but orders.php for newest versions of woocommerce.